# Blogger or Wordpress, which has better integration with Ubuntu?

Tags: 11.10

About to start my own blog about Ubuntu on my fresh 11.10 install. I would like to know the pros and cons of using either platform in a Ubuntu environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blogger works perfectly well in Ubuntu (I believe that Wordpress should be ok too, as both are web based).

I recommend Blogger, since it has more resources than Wordpress.com.

Wordpress.org is the GPL version that can be downloaded (but requires a paid hosting service) it's better. But if you want it for free, go with Blogger.

Comment: How do I get the plugins for blogger like a nice mobile plugin that converts a blog for mobile viewing

Comment: Blogger has his own mobile version, that can be activated in configurations.

Check out my blog on a cell phone, so you can see how the mobile version looks like. www.geekverse.net (It's in portuguese, I'm from Brazil.)

Answer (score 2):

Where will it be hosted? You can't host blogger on your own computer while you can do that with Wordpress. If you'll be using their online services (blogger.com or wordpress.com) for the blog hosting, then it really doesn't matter which from Ubuntu's perspective.

Comment: To be hosted on their servers not on locally

Comment: Then it really doesn't matter which because you'll only be using a browser to interact with them.